# How to remove a package whose correct name you don't know?

Tags: command-line, apt, software-center, uninstall

I had downloaded arc-theme-solid_1450051815.946cbf5_all.deb file from http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/Horst3180/xUbuntu_15.04/all/ and had installed it using the Software Center but when I decided to uninstall it wasn't showing up in the Software Center. I thought of removing it via the terminal but couldn't think of the correct name of the package to uninstall. This has been the general problem associated with installing any package outside the Software Center. Also, is the name of the package to uninstall the same as that of the .deb file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to use `dpkg -I` or `dpkg-deb -I` to show information about a package by reading the deb file. From `man dpkg`

```
   dpkg-deb actions
          See  dpkg-deb(1)  for  more  information  about  the   following
          actions.
          .
          .
          .
          -I, --info archive [control-file...]
              Show information about a package.
```

e.g.

```
$ dpkg -I arc-theme-solid_1450051815.946cbf5_all.deb
 new debian package, version 2.0.
 size 286706 bytes: control archive=42665 bytes.
     421 bytes,    12 lines      control              
  147142 bytes,  1477 lines      md5sums              
 Package: arc-theme-solid
 Version: 1450051815.946cbf5
 Architecture: all
 Maintainer: Horst3180 <horst3180@gmx.net>
 Installed-Size: 4307
 Depends: gnome-themes-standard, gtk2-engines-murrine
 Conflicts: arc-theme
 Replaces: arc-theme
 Section: misc
 Priority: optional
 Description: Arc is a theme for GTK 3, GTK 2 and Gnome-Shell.
  It supports GTK 3 and GTK 2 based desktop environments like Gnome, Unity, Budgie, Pantheon, etc.
```

So in this case, the package name is `arc-theme-solid`

Comment: What to do in case of the error  **dpkg-deb: error: failed to read archive `arc-theme-solid_1450051815.946cbf5_all.deb': No such file or directory** ?

Comment: @rochakgupta make sure you are executing the command from the directory containing the deb file (or prepend the path to the file)

Answer (score 4):

***Use Synaptic Package Manager*** (GUI Method)

1. Install synaptic package manager

   `sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get upgrade
   sudo apt-get install synaptic`
2. Open synaptic package manager and select "*status*" option.

[image]

3. Select "Installed(Local or obsolete)".

[image]

4. Select the package you want to remove. Right click -> Remove the package.

[image]

5. Click "Apply".

[image]

Comment: Great GUI method!

Answer (score 2):

> Is the name of the package to uninstall the same as that of the .deb file?

Not necessarily. The package file could be called `install-me.deb`, and the package itself could be `foo-bar`.

However `arc-theme-solid_1450051815.946cbf5_all.deb` looks like a normal name. In general, for a package, the `.deb` file should be named `<package-name>_<version>_<architecture>.deb`. For the package you installed, then:

- Name: `arc-theme-solid`
- Version: `1450051815.946cbf5`
- Architecture: `all`

To verify, if you still have the `.deb` file, you can use `dpkg-deb` on it:

```
dpkg-deb --field arc-theme-solid_1450051815.946cbf5_all.deb
```

For example:

```
$ dpkg-deb --field fonts-noto_2015-09-29-1_all.deb
Package: fonts-noto
Version: 2015-09-29-1
Architecture: all
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Debian Fonts Task Force <pkg-fonts-devel@lists.alioth.debian.org>
Installed-Size: 22
Depends: fonts-noto-hinted
Recommends: fonts-noto-unhinted, fonts-noto-cjk
Section: fonts
...
```

Comment: Thanks for clearing my doubt regarding the package name!

Answer (score 0):

## How to search for the package?

If you think you know **part of the name**, you can use `dpkg` to search the names of installed packages (it actually calls `dpkg-query`):

```
dpkg -l "*arc-theme*"
```

If you know **one of the files that belongs to the package**, you can again use `dpkg` to find which package that file is from.  Use the full path of the file.

```
dpkg -S /full/path/to/file
```

One of these techniques might help you to find the package's full name.